# Study of selection higher stages for a multistage rocket

Tags: thrust, stages, altitude, first-stage

Will it be correct to say that the thrust produced by the first stage is the ultimate limiting factor for a rocket's ability? The logic behind this thought is like this: Higher quantity of its propellant to achieve longer firing time & consequently higher altitude, adds to the "payload" (total weight / mass to be lifted by first stage) and limits the altitude to which it can travel. The difference between first stage's lifting capacity, and the actual weight of the total first state (inclusive of propellant tanks etc.) is the "available" margin to add higher stages.

Comment: Strangely phrased, the question heading and content seem to not match very well.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the total thrust of the first stage is the ultimate arbiter of ability, for a vertically launched, rocket-thrust-only rocket. (no carrier craft, aerodynamic wings, airbreather engines, or any other funny stuff)

This because, quite obviously, you can only fly to space that which you can lift off the ground to start with.

After that it becomes more complex very quickly, as Thrust-to-weight ratio comes in, and  the ISP achieved by your first stage engines, and the stage mass ratio, and the propellant mass ratio, and aerodynamics, and flight path chosen, and, and, and.

But as the ultimate ground floor entry... you must be able to lift your total rocket stack off the ground, and that is purely dependent on the total sum of thrust available at launch. The launch thrust *must* be greater than the launch weight, and most rockets use a Thrust-to-Weight Ratio of between 1.2 and 1.8, because if your thrust just matches your weight (TWR=1) then you will go nowhere, burning fuel just to fight gravity. (Like that Astra rocket and its sideways dance, until you burn off enough fuel to be lighter)

Comment: really cute answer there. thanks. I appreciate your use of words. I came to know few more topics I should study more about. Thanks again. By the way, can you please advise me on correctly phrasing the question? I tried to match the heading and the content to the best of my abilities in terms of knowledge of the subject, and off course that of English language.

Comment: Your heading talks about the selection criteria for upper stages. Your body of question asks just one question, about the ultimate thrust of the first stage. Both are valid questions, and vaguely related, but would not receive anything like the same answer, because they ask very different things. You could study a lot about the relative importance of various aspects, optimal staging efficiencies, etc. But honestly? Play some of the game "Kerbal Space Program". It is a game but close enough to an actual simulation that it teaches you a *lot* about rockets, orbital dynamics, etc.

Comment: @Niranjan, agreed with CuteKitty too. Suggest that your heading could be changed to something in this direction "In a multi-stage rocket, when the first stage is fully designed, which limits does it put on the capability of the remainder of the rocket?" (if my guess of your motivation is correct).

Comment: @Cutekitty, OK agreed. Perhaps I am in the habit of digging in technical things, and realize that many things are inter related. I hope you would find my next question more specific. Thanks for your post.

Comment: @Ng, OK agreed. You have put the same question in a more specific term of reference (that of a fully designed rocket). I had a more generic question in my mind, so that a designer of a rocket knows the limitations of what he can achieve, with the kind of first stage he has. I thought this he should know beforehand. But your suggestion is welcome.

Comment: @Niranjan, then I leave it to you to do the edit. A clear question is worth 10 answers!